# Wellmate water pressure dropped

Tags: well, well-pump

Our water pressure dropped and the washing machine won't work, which is so bad.

I went out to check the pressure in the well house and it says 30 psi.

[image: gauge]

Looking at the square D 9013 FTG-2 pressure switch [instructions](https://www.pumpsukltd.com/square-d-pressure-switch-9013fsg2.html) It says the following:

[image]

That's only an example and there's lots of devices in the datasheet.  This is the FSG variant, (there's not FTG varaint listed so switch must be old!):

[image]

It is wired like this :

[image]

The right live (brown wire) is active and the left live is off.

I assuming that it's mechanical and when a pressure differential is hit the pump comes on.  I do not understand the wiring.  The inactive wiring goes to this junction box:

[image]

I checked the switch and it is working.  I don't know why there is a 20uF capacitor in the junction box.  Note the power is off!

I check across the capacitor and I'm getting about 8 uF.  My multimeter hasn't been calibrated and I'm guessing it's my meter not the cap.

The wires exit on the cap side and go... somewhere underground.

I want to get the pressure back above 40 psi.

My questions

1. Is there a way of increasing the cut-in to 35psi?
2. What the heck is the capcitor doing in the junction box?

**edit**

I emptied the faucet as @crip659
After a while it started to run out.  I do not know why I thought the well pressure was natural!  I put everything back together and the motor started working again however the problem persists.  The pressure is too low and it seems to switch off a 30 psi.  I know what @crip659 is saying regarding washing machine but that's not the problem, the water starts to run out on the tap too beside the washer.  The pressue is really low.  I need to get the supply up to at least 35psi.

Any idea how to change the cut-in setting?

Comment: So what"s the question?

Comment: Drain/open a faucet to see if it brings the pressure back up.  Also check the filters on the washer's water lines.  30 pounds should be enough for the washer to fill, if a bit slower.

Comment: @JACK apologies published early as pictures all disappeared!

Comment: @crip659 I think the pressure might be the well itself as I've never heard the pump activate.  This means the well pressure if 30psi will not let the switch come on.

Comment: Opening a faucet will drop the pressure below 30 pounds.  I have a feeling that the filters in the washer hoses are blocked with sediment.  Turn off the water to the washer and remove the hoses.  The filters should be easy to pop out and clean.

Comment: @crip659 you were correct.  However, the problem is not the washing machine, the sink beside the washing machine is not working suffciently either and neither is the dish washer.  The tap coughs and sputters and some flow comes out for aout 10 seconds and is then gone again.  Maybe an airlock (unlikely) or blockage.  My thoughts are increase the pressure and hopefully that'll knock out a blockage/ airlock.

Comment: I've certainly seen prettier terminal connections. I'd start by stripping to fresh, bright copper and either crimping on fork terminals or at least adding some dielectric grease to help maintain better contact.

Comment: The nut and bolt at the top of the pressure switch is the adjustment screw.  I think you tighten it down to raise pressure.  I would also turn off the power and have a good look at the points to see if they are pitted.  If pitted, then it will be a good idea to get a new switch.

Answer (score 0):

The pressure gauge is broken.  As @crip659 said opening the faucet should show a drop in pressure.  In my delirium, I started to think that there was a 30psi natural pressure.

I loosened the mains tap or at least banged it and a lot of brown water came out.  No matter what happens the gauge says 30 psi.  I'm assuming it's broken.

If anyone is reading this I've worked with electrical systems and studied electronic engineering.  Be very careful with all the electricity.